# PowerBi Count minium values

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-desktop, powerbi-custom-visuals

i need your help calculating following:
based on the region and value(left table), i need to calculate the number of minium values displayed.
For instance, Value 5 is the minium value 3 times. Which function allow me to get that, i'm not able to find a right answer for days.
any idea is welcome!
many thanks

[See data as example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MOw8H.jpg)

Comment: Hi there, what have you tried so far?

Answer (score 1):

Use the following DAX measure to achieve your goal:

```
CountMinValue= 
  VAR __value = SELECTEDVALUE( 'Table'[Value] )
  Return CALCULATE( COUNT( 'Table'[Min Value]), 'Table'[Min Value] = __value )
```

[image]

Comment: Many thanks agustin for your help. Considering i dont have Min Value calculate It, i'll calculate It separatelly and call It from your sentence. Is that a good approach?

Comment: I thougt that you already have that column calculated. Use the following DAX code to create that column: 
Min Value = 
VAR __country = 'Table'[Country]
VAR __subTable = FILTER( 'Table', 'Table'[Country] = __country )
Return CALCULATE( MIN( 'Table'[Value] ), __subTable )